# Stop google speech to text streaming recognize client in python

Tags: python, google-cloud-speech

I use google speech to text API to transcript voice to text.
I am trying to terminate this service when we hit the **is_final=True**

```
requests = (types.StreamingRecognizeRequest(audio_content=message.chunk)
                for message in messages)

responses = client.streaming_recognize(streaming_config, requests)
```

I have tried: **responses.cancel()** but it is coming up with error

I found that in **Java** there is this method available to terminate streaming recognition service:

```
SpeechClient speech;
speech.close();
```

But I can not find the same method in Python client library. Can somebody guide me how to terminate streaming service properly in Python?

Comment: The `StreamingRecognizeResponse` can include multiple results with `is_final=True`, are you looking just for the first one? If so, maybe what you're looking for is setting [`single_utterance=True`](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/speech/gapic/v1p1beta1/types.html#google.cloud.speech_v1p1beta1.types.StreamingRecognitionConfig.single_utterance). If you do so, the client will close the stream when there's a pause returning just one result with the `is_final` flag set to true.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I haven't read the documentation carefully, you are true, this is a way to close the stream

Answer (score 0):

Like Leferis S already mentioned. If you want to stop a `StreamingRecognizeRequest` after receiving `is_final=True` you have to set `single_utterance=True` inside your [StreamingRecognitionConfig](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/speech/gapic/v1/types.html#google.cloud.speech_v1.types.StreamingRecognitionConfig).

An extended solution would be to parse the responses. [Here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/speech/cloud-client/transcribe_streaming_mic.py) (line 147-160) is an official example, where you can see how to exit the streaming process if a special word was finally recognized.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, I think the first solution from Leferis S is suitable for my use case, have a nice day!